# XamlParseException when I inherit a Page from a Generic base class

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm currently working with this exact code:

```cs
public class ViewModelAwarePage<T> : Page
{        
}

public class BaseMainMenuView 
    : ViewModelAwarePage<String>
{     
}

public sealed partial class MainMenuView
    : BaseMainMenuView
{
    public MainMenuView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And xaml:

```
<local:BaseMainMenuView
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="Tutorial.UI.WinRT.Views.MainMenuView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Tutorial.UI.WinRT.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundBrush}">

</Grid>

</local:BaseMainMenuView>
```

When I try to construct this page then I get the error "BaseMainMenuView does not support Grid as content"

> Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2144665590   Message=BaseMainMenuView does not support Grid
>   as content. [Line: 12 Position: 22]   Source=""   StackTrace:
>          at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation
>   componentResourceLocation)
>          at Tutorial.UI.WinRT.Views.MainMenuView.InitializeComponent() in c:\Projects\Misc\MvvmCross\Sample -
>   Tutorial\Tutorial\Tutorial.UI.WinRT\obj\x86\Debug\Views\MainMenuView.g.i.cs:line
>   34
>          at Tutorial.UI.WinRT.Views.MainMenuView..ctor() in c:\Projects\Misc\MvvmCross\Sample -
>   Tutorial\Tutorial\Tutorial.UI.WinRT\Views\MainMenuView.xaml.cs:line 40
>          at Tutorial.UI.WinRT.XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_3_MainMenuView()
>   in c:\Projects\Misc\MvvmCross\Sample -
>   Tutorial\Tutorial\Tutorial.UI.WinRT\obj\x86\Debug\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs:line
>   122
>          at Tutorial.UI.WinRT.XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance() in
>   c:\Projects\Misc\MvvmCross\Sample -
>   Tutorial\Tutorial\Tutorial.UI.WinRT\obj\x86\Debug\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs:line
>   314   InnerException:

If I try reducing the code to:

```cs
public class ViewModelAwarePage : Page
{        
}

public class BaseMainMenuView 
    : ViewModelAwarePage
{     
}

public sealed partial class MainMenuView
    : BaseMainMenuView
{
    public MainMenuView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

then the page loads fine.

I don't understand the exception at all - all the Bing/Google hits I find for it, suggest Silverlight 2 problems.

Can anyone explain the error - can anyone suggest ideas for how I might be able to inherit from a generic page?

Answer (score 1):

Stuart please try this on the Release Preview as I believe this to be fixed

Comment: I ran into this exact problem this week, and I am working with Win8 RTM and Visual Studio 2012 Update 1, any ideas?