# MvvmCross: How to prevent casting ViewModel?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I noticed that in v3, MvvmCross removed the generic declaration `<TViewModel>` on `MvxTouchViewController` and renamed it to `MvxViewController`.

This means the `ViewModel` property is typed as a generic interface of `IMvxViewModel` rather than the specific `TViewModel`.

If I need to access the `TViewModel` in my view controller, is there a convenient way of getting the ViewModel already cast to the specific instance type for this View?  Or do I have to cast it myself every time?

Comment: I appreciate I'm often the first to answer for MvvmCross questions, but please phrase questions for everyone not just for 'you' :) See 'make it relevant' in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous Generic-based MvvmCross Views were removed from MvvmCross mainly because of the threat of 'Heizenbugs' in the objective-C based platforms.

For what little anyone knows about `Heizenbugs`, see http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/771/exporting-generic-type-to-objc-supported

I don't believe I ever saw an Heizenbug, but Xamarin were **very clear** in their advice to avoid them at all costs - for example, they twice changed the compiler to issue **errors** for our generics. Indeed, on .Mac such generic code remains an error today, while on .iOS it's just a **very scary warning**.

---

Added to this, we did also encounter some issues with Xaml based platforms when inheriting from Generic base classes - although these were mainly resolved (e.g. [XamlParseException when I inherit a Page from a Generic base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699215/xamlparseexception-when-i-inherit-a-page-from-a-generic-base-class))

(Aside - to allow some backwards compatibility, WindowsPhone does still have some limited generic View support, but this is marked as `Obsolete` and I do regret allowing this to live on...)

---

The good news is that, in my experience, the majority of Views do not need to know their ViewModel type - instead, the majority of Views can be built with 'pure bindings' without declaring a typed ViewModel.

For those remaining Views which do need to know their ViewModel type, then a simple added property quickly adds this - e.g.:

```
protected MyViewModel MyViewModel
{
    get { return (MyViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
    /* set is optional - not typically needed 
    set { base.ViewModel = value; } 
    */
}
```

Alternatively you can probably write an extension method for this if you want to - e.g. something like:

```
public static TViewModel TypedViewModel<TViewModel>(this IMvxView view) where TViewModel : class, IMvxViewModel
{
    return view.ViewModel as TViewModel;
}
```

---

Very alternatively....

.... If you are not scared of ghosts, goblins or `Heizenbugs`....

One way to add the `TypedViewModel` property to all of your views would be to add generics back into your view hierarchy - this is easy for you to do - e.g. in Android adding

```
public class BaseActivity<TViewModel> : MvxActivity 
   where TViewModel : class, IMvxViewModel
{
    protected TViewModel TypedViewModel
    {
        get { return (TViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        /* set is optional - not typically needed 
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
        */
    }
}
```

This should work fine for you... but if you hit an Heizenbug, then I don't think anyone will be able to assist you. Xamarin have been very clear in recommending against this pattern - especially on the objC based platforms.

Answer (score 0):

As of 3.5, generic based views are supported again as apparently the underlying Xamarin issue has been fixed.

http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/mvvmcross-v35-pushed-to-stable.html